# 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise' error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I am new to Angular 2, and Angular as well, and I am running into this issue related to promises.

I have this file name module.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Module } from './module.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ModuleService {
  getModules(): Promise<Module[]> {
    // TODO: Switch to a real service.
    return Promise.resolve([{
      uiid: "text",
      type: "ahahaha"
    }]);
  }
}
```

Which call module.entity which contains this code:

```
export class Module {
  uuid: string = '00000';
  type: string = 'TextComponent';
  // Maps ModuleSlots to modules
  submodules: {[key: string]: [Module]} = {};
}
```

But running `npm starts` returns this error to me:

> Type 'Promise<{ uiid: string; type: string; }[]>' is not assignable to
>   type 'Promise'.   Type '{ uiid: string; type: string; }[]'
>   is not assignable to type 'Module[]'.
>       Type '{ uiid: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Module'.
>         Property 'uuid' is missing in type '{ uiid: string; type: string; }'.

Can anybody gives me a hint about what's not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message already gives you a hint

```
Property 'uuid' is missing in type '{ uiid: string; type: string; }'
```

declaration:

```
uuid: string = '00000';
 ^^
```

value:

```
uiid: "text",
 ^^
```